# How do you get the imaginary number 'i' by itself JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, complex-numbers

I'm transferring some code from Python into JavaScript. Just wondering how I could get the number 'i' in JavaScript (in Python its just 1j).

Comment: No such number type exists. Either use a library, or implement all the necessary logic yourself

Comment: Maybe soon: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-extended-numeric-literals…